# Run different frameworks side-by-side with OWIN

Tags: .net, owin

My impression of one of the big benefits of Owin is that it makes it easy to run different web frameworks side-by-side without IIS's `IHttpHandler`. (This would be huge for distributing vertical functionality slices as nuget features.)

However every tutorial and article I find talks of things like self-host and a single framework. This is not what I'm interested in, I'm interested in running mvc, nancy, web api, maybe even webforms in the same application.

Am I wrong about OWIN enabling this? Say I want

- Mvc to handle most requests
- Webforms to handle requests which have a version=legacy header
- Nancy to handle requests to /Nancy/...

How would I configure my `Startup` class to enable this?

Comment: In theory what you suggest should be possible, but in practice there are few standards that allow these pieces from different authors to work together. I am building OWIN.Framework NuGet that addresses this, but it's at a fairly early stage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although the use case sounds a bit absurd, you're absolutely right that OWIN enables this. You can compose your pipeline in all kinds of crazy ways.

### Straight Pipeline

A typical "straight" pipeline would look something like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWebApi(new MyHttpConfiguration());
        app.MapSignalR();
        app.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

This will work as follows (given you're hosting on `http://localhost/`)

- WebAPI - `http://localhost/api/*` (default routing)
- SignalR - `http://localhost/signalr` (default route)
- Nancy - `http://localhost/*` (will handle everything else)

### Branched Pipeline

You can also create branches in your pipeline:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWebApi(new MyHttpConfiguration());

        app.Map("/newSite", site =>
        {
            site.MapSignalR();
            site.UseNancy();
        });
    }
}
```

This will work as follows (given you're hosting on `http://localhost/`)

- WebAPI - `http://localhost/api/*` (default routing)
- SignalR - `http://localhost/newSite/signalr` (default route)
- Nancy - `http://localhost/newSite/*` (will handle everything else)

Comment: Ah thanks. My use case at the moment is just a simple playground project. The end goal is to be able to write the JasmineTest nuget package (of which I'm the maintainer) as an owin module rather than a controller distributed via content.

Comment: What nuget is `MapPath` in? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: There's `MapWhen` is that what you meant? The straight pipeline stuff didn't work but I was able to get it working with `MapWhen`

Comment: It looks like it's just `Map` now... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.mapextensions(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: MapWhen is for your second sample, where you want to inspect headers etc. before determining if you want to go down that branch.

Comment: [Jabbr](https://github.com/jabbr/jabbr) is a great example. Check out [their startup class](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR/blob/e40634b4e6594ce4ebd6aea0a6864b8f61b1ed02/JabbR/App_Start/Startup.cs).

Comment: Good link for code samples of all strategies => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/katana-samples