# How to manage IAppBuilder mapping at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I'm trying to use Branched Pipeline to defined some sort of virtual directory.

a good example is done here: [Run different frameworks side-by-side with OWIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215428/run-different-frameworks-side-by-side-with-owin)

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWebApi(new MyHttpConfiguration());
        app.Map("/newSite", site =>
        {
            site.MapSignalR();
            site.UseNancy();
        });
    }
}
```

Here I can have a virtual directory newSite with a custom HttpConfiguration.

This configuration is done in the Startup class and it works.
But I would like to be able to add/change the IAppBuilder at runtime during the lifetime of the App.
Indeed I'm using the SelfHost Server and I would like to create new virtual directory (or subsite or anything else) using a admin console to create a pluggable architecture with differents component (api/authorization handler etc...) with configuration at runtime.

Is it possible?

I don't know where I can apply a new configuration during runtime

Thanks a lot

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to adjust the OWIN configuration after it has been set.

The only alternative is to simply restart your server, making the `Configuration` method run again.